# Another exception was thrown: type 'RxList<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Vehicle>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to implement search functionality from database but it shows type cast error

```
Another exception was thrown: type 'RxList<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Vehicle>' in type cast
```

In my Vehicle_Controller class

```
final vehicleList = [].obs;

Future<void> getVehicles() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> vehicleDetails = await DBHelper.query();
    vehicleList.assignAll(vehicleDetails.map((data) => Vehicle.fromJson(data)).toList());
  }
```

I want to implement search in my search class

```
final _vehicleController = Get.put(VehicleController());
List<Vehicle> _list;
List<Vehicle> _searchList = List();

void initState() {
super.initState();
_IsSearching = false;
    
_list = _vehicleController.vehicleList as List<Vehicle>; //type cast error 

_searchList = _list;

_searchQuery.addListener(() {
  if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchText = "";
      _buildSearchList();
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _IsSearching = true;
      _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
      _buildSearchList();
    });
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `_vehicleController.vehicleList.value` as `vehicleList` is -like the exception says- a `RxList` not a `List`

also update this line to be a `<Vehicle>[]`.

```
final vehicleList = <Vehicle>[].obs;
```

this will make `vehicleList` of type `RxList<Vehicle>`

Comment: Another exception was thrown: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Vehicle>' in type cast